# JavaFX FileChooser: how to set file filters?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, filechooser

I want to set file filters in a JavaFX FileChooser but I could not find a way to do it.

My code:

```
  FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
  fc.setTitle("My File Chooser");
  File f = fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
  System.out.println(f);
```

Comment: I don't have experience, but it sounds like it's similar to code in this thread: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10333202

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You could do:

```
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
```

Here is a simple example:

```
public class ExtensionFilterExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Extension Filter Example");

        final Label fileLabel = new Label();

        Button btn = new Button("Open FileChooser");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

                // Set extension filter
                FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = 
                        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TEXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
                fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

                // Show open file dialog
                File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
                if (file != null) {
                    fileLabel.setText(file.getPath());
                }
            }
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox(30);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(fileLabel, btn);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it really works. I saw the getExtensionFilters() in the documentation, but I was expecting something like addExtensionFilter() or setExtensionFilters().

Comment: Can FileChooser be reused here or does it have to be created for each event occurrence?

Answer (score 20):

Update for JavaFX plus multiple extensions filter:

```
FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();

FileChooser.ExtensionFilter fileExtensions = 
  new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
    "Web pages", "*.tpl", "*.html", "*.htm");

fc.getExtensionFilters().add(fileExtensions);
```

Answer (score -2):

This is How you can do it.

```
FileChooser fc=new FileChooser();
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter fileExtensions =new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("music files","*.mp3", "*.mp4");
fc.getExtensionFilters().add(fileExtensions);
List<File> selectedFiles=fc.showOpenMultipleDialog(null);       
if(selectedFiles!=null){
     for(int i=0;i<selectedFiles.size();i++){
           System.out.println(selectedFiles.get(i).toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the answer provided by @Zon